# yii2, relations, как получить count()

Tags: php, yii2, relation, active-record

я пытаюсь получить количество видео из таблицы videos(),

в модуле `user` я сделал функцию

```
 public function getVideos(){
    return $this->hasMany(Videos::className(), ['id_user' => 'id'])->count();
}
```

в контроллере у меня

```
$customers = $modelUser::find()->where(['id' => $userId])->with('videos')->all();
```

На сколько я понял, проблема заключается в `->all()`

как мне полуть количество? я получаю ошибку типа `common\models\User has no relation named "videos".`

Comment: Все верно, getVideos() должен возвращать связь, а он у вас возвращает count. Уберите count() из hasMany() и попробуйте его прописать вместо all()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в моделе

```php
/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getVideos(){
    return $this->hasMany(Videos::className(), ['id_user' => 'id']);
}

/**
 * @return integer
 */
public function getVideosCnt(){
    return $this->getVideos()->count();
}
```

В контроллере

```php
$user = User::findOne(100); // 100 - существующий id пользователя
echo $user->videosCnt; // кол-во видео
```

Comment: Это до конца правильно вызывать 2 раза getVIdeos?сразу от запроса findOne, а затем ->videosCnt. Возможно есть вариант получше?

Comment: Почему 2 раза? При findOne getVideos() не исполняется. От отработает только один раз при $this->videosCnt